# Запретить доступ к папке на время работы программы

Tags: java

Есть ли способ в Java запретить всем, кроме программы, любой доступ к папке на время выполнения кода программы? Гуглил - не нашел ничего, что соответствовало бы моим требованиям.

Comment: в java точно нет. так как java работает внутри виртуальной машины. можно сделать это средствами ОС (работает не для всех ОС).

Comment: А какую изначальную задачу Вы решаете?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov задание - написать "хеш-антивирусник". у таких вещей есть папка карантин. и как её сделать недоступной.  Это универное задание, так что...))

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
File file = new File(myPath);
file.setExecutable(false, false);
file.setReadable(false, false);
file.setWritable(false, false);
file.setReadOnly();
```